# SLURM automatically limit memory/cpu usage depending on GRES

Tags: slurm

Given that a single node has multiple GPUs, is there a way to automatically limit CPU and memory usage depending on the number of GPUs requested?

In particular, if the users job script requests 2 GPUs then the job should automatically be restricted to `2*BaseMEM` and `2*BaseCPU`, where `BaseMEM = TotalMEM/numGPUs` and `BaseCPU=numCPUs/numGPUs`, which would be defined on a per node basis.

Is it possible to configure SLURM this way? If not, can one alternatively "virtually" split a multi-GPU machine into multiple nodes with the appropriate CPU and MEM count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line

```
--cpus-per-gpu $BaseCPU --mem-per-gpu $BaseMEM
```

In slurm.conf

```
DefMemPerGPU=1234
DefCpuPerGPU=1
```

Since you can't use variables in slurm.conf, you would need to write a little bash command to calculate $BaseCPU and $BaseMEM

Comment: Nice! I didn't see this because we have been running an older version. It appears this feature became available in version 19.05 (May 2019).